# How to use input bindings for commands when WPF content is hosted in WinForms

Tags: wpf, elementhost, inputbinding

I have Windows Forms windows with tab control and one of its tab hosts ElementHost with ContentControl as child element. This control has collection of input bindings which work only when any child element has input focus but if focus is lost they no longer react. Is it possible to define these input bindings on a higher level in such situation?

Comment: Could you post some code to make it more concrete? What do your bindings look like and what is your proposal for placing them on a higher level (of which I think will not be a good solution)

Comment: Binding are quite simple, somehting like 
<ContentControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command={Binding MyCommand} Key="R" Modifiers="Control" />
</ContentControl.InputBindings>

Comment: And if windows forms content somehow get focus those key bindings are no longer can be activated. In WPF you can put your bindings into Window element and everything will work

Comment: Tommorow I will have a look in code I have on my external drive at home. I had a similiar problem with a WPF Page in a WinForms Elementhost. Be patient ;)

Comment: I set up the same situation and can reproduce the "bug". Did some googling and read several posts here and there but no succes so far :( Maybe I will have a closer look later on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution might be to pass (tunnel) keyboard and/or mouse events from Win Forms to WPF host. I made the following proof of concept. It works but has limitations and requires more work. Firstly you will need a class derived from *ElementHost*. You should use it in your application instead of the standard *ElementHost*. This new custom class will have only one additional method *ProcessWinFormsKeys* which will map WinForms specific keys to those used by WPF. Then it will find a proper input binding and execute it.

```
    public class CustomElementHost : ElementHost
    {
        public void ProcessWinFormsKeys(Keys keys, Keys modifiers)
        {
            var key = KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey((int)keys);

            var modifier = System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.None;

            if ((modifiers & Keys.Control) != 0)
                modifier |= System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.Control;

            if ((modifiers & Keys.Shift) != 0)
                modifier |= System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.Shift;

            if ((modifiers & Keys.Alt) != 0)
                modifier |= System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.Alt;

            foreach (InputBinding inputBinding in Child.InputBindings)
            {
                var keyGesture = inputBinding.Gesture as KeyGesture;

                if (keyGesture == null) 
                    continue;

                if(keyGesture.Key == key && keyGesture.Modifiers == modifier)
                    if(inputBinding.Command.CanExecute(inputBinding.CommandParameter))
                        inputBinding.Command.Execute(inputBinding.CommandParameter);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in your *Form* that contains an instance of *CustomElementHost* you should subscribe *KeyDown* event and call *ProcessWinFormsKeys* method within a handler:

```
    public Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        KeyPreview = true;
        KeyDown += Form_KeyDown;
        ...
    }

    void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
       elementHost.ProcessWinFormsKeys(e.KeyCode, e.Modifiers);
    }
```

Another solution might be to utilize global hot keys. It will require to use *RegisterHotKey* function from user32.dll. However, I'm not sure if it will work with *ElementHost*. If you want to try there are a few questions on stackoverflow and dozens of article in Internet.